# Can a Netgear Wireless Cable Modem Gateway (CG814GCMR) be used as a normal wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, cable, modem

It looks like the idea for this thing is that it's a cable modem and wireless router all in one.  But it doesn't seem to be working as a cable modem and I have another cable modem that does work.  Can I still use the Netgear device as a wireless router?  It has no "incoming ethernet jack", just 4 presumably outgoing ethernet jacks not distinguished from each other.  But perhaps you can connect the cable modem to one of those jacks with an ethernet cable and it will work like a normal router.  I expected that to work but didn't have any luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it.

The router normally would become the gateway by redirecting all local network traffic through the WAN (cable) connection.  This modem doesn't have a WAN port so there's no other way for it to gain access to the WAN.  It could be used as a wireless bridge (i.e., a range extender), but that would require another router connected to the cable.

I think your best bet here would be to figure out why it's not working as a cable modem and try to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Thompson. Just wanted to point out as a WAG that perhaps your cable company needs to provision the router. If you just bought the router, hooked it up to your coax, and found that it didn't work, provisioning is probably the issue. It depends on your cable company whether you have to call them or if the cable company has software so you can do it yourself.